# How to enable a table layout which has many column to fit in a horizontal scrollview in Android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, horizontalscrollview

I need to create a table layout in my application. However, the table consists of many columns which cannot be separated. Hence, i want to put the table layout inside the horizontal scrollview.

Here is my xml code.

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFA500"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:text="@string/send"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="false"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/myRecycle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearid"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Recyclerview xml which consists of the table layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<HorizontalScrollView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
            <TableRow
                android:background="@drawable/border"

                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tnameresult"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/dem"

                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:padding="3dip" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tcompresult"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/dem"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:padding="3dip" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is my table layout display, the column width and height won't auto stretch by itself. Can someone teach me on how to do it? Thank you :)

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HorizontalScrollView you need horizontal layout manager.

**Try this code in your java class:**

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view); 
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) , but this code made all the row become a new column